snap prevents Disk Devices from being accessed
I wanted to backup the device my /boot partition is mounted on using mozilla. But snap prevents me from doing that.
I use fsck here to illustrate what is happening - clonezilla seems to work when fsck works.
I started by unmounting /boot:
sudo umount /boot/efi 
sudo umount /boot
sudo fsck /dev/sda2  # which is the device for /boot

From that I get the error message
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/sda2 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

My question is: How can I get fsck to run?

The current workaround is:

snap disable all installed snaps
sudo systemctl stop snapd
reboot

Then everything works.
But there must be a simpler way of accessing /dev/sda2! How can I access it without the interference of snap?
